# Qual a diferença entre o método join() e a declaração synchronized?

Tags: java

Estou com dificuldades em saber qual a diferença entre o método **join()** e o   modificador **synchronized**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join()` interrompe a execução da *thread* atual até que a *thread* que invocou o método `join()` seja completamente executada.

`synchronized` previne que múltiplas *threads* executem um bloco de código ou acessem uma variável ao mesmo tempo.